# actionscript 3, SoundChannel, and SoundChannel.position

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

SoundChannel has an element that is called "position", and unless I am completely misreading everything, that is supposed to be where you find the position currently being played in milliseconds.

I'm tracing through this using FlashDevelop, and that number is *always* zero!  I'm checking the address of the SoundChannel allocated, and it's the right one.  But position always stays at zero.

Am I missing something?  Yes, I can use a timer, but this sure seemed like a quick way to do a pause with a really easy way to restart playback...

Comment: Please provide some code that displays your problem. It's possible you are allocating another `SoundChannel` and query that one's `position`, of course it's 0.

Comment: Maybe my post was unclear. I am tracing through the code, checking the address of the SoundChannel when it is first allocated, and making sure it is the same when I am looking for the position.  It's the same SoundChannel, and position is always 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, it was just a matter of organization.  I was turning the track off in another part of the code before I checked for location.